QR code scanning with Expo v.51 is not working
While trying to use expo-camera with the latest Expo version 51 in a react native project and Android , it seems that there is no ability to scan any kind of code. While turning my camera to a QR code, literally nothing happens. I use the code below:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { CameraView, useCameraPermissions } from 'expo-camera';

import Screen from './Screen';
import TextHyperlink from '../components/TextHyperlink';

function ScannerScreen() {
    const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
    const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
    const [permission, requestPermission] = useCameraPermissions();

    if (!permission) {
        return <View />;
    }

    if (!permission.granted) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                    We need your permission to show the camera
                </Text>
                <Button onPress={requestPermission} title='grant permission' />
            </View>
        );
    }

    const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ data }) => {
        if (data) {
            setScanned(true);
            setResult(data);
        }
    };

    const handleResult = () => {
        if (!result) return null;

        if (result.startsWith('http')) {
            return (
                <TextHyperlink
                    style={styles.resultlink}
                    text={result}
                    url={result}
                />
            );
        } else {
            return <Text style={styles.resulttext}>{result}</Text>;
        }
    };

    return (
        <Screen>
            <View style={styles.camerabox}>
                <CameraView
                    barcodeScannerSettings={{
                        barcodeTypes: [
                            'aztec',
                            'ean13',
                            'ean8',
                            'qr',
                            'pdf417',
                            'upc_e',
                            'datamatrix',
                            'code39',
                            'code93',
                            'itf14',
                            'codabar',
                            'code128',
                            'upc_a',
                        ],
                    }}
                    onBarCodeScanned={
                        scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned
                    }
                    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
                />
                {scanned && (
                    <Button
                        title={'Tap to Scan Again'}
                        onPress={() => setScanned(false)}
                    />
                )}
            </View>
            <View style={styles.textbox}>{handleResult()}</View>
        </Screen>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    camerabox: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: '100%',
    },
    resultlink: {
        color: 'blue',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        fontFamily: 'monospace',
        padding: 20,
        textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    },
    resulttext: {
        color: 'white',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        fontFamily: 'monospace',
        padding: 20,
    },
    textbox: {
        borderTopColor: 'blue',
        borderTopWidth: 3,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: '100%',
    },
});

export default ScannerScreen;


Dependencies used:
"expo": "~51.0.21"
"expo-camera": "^15.0.14"
"react-native": "0.74.3"

Expo 51 uses expo-camera with  and useCameraPermissions(), instead of  and requestCameraPermissionsAsync().
The fact is that my code worked perfectly with Expo 50.

In Expo 51, unlike previous versions, the onBarCodeScanned has been converted to onBarcodeScanned.


Note that I've replaced CameraView with Camera from expo-camera, and added the BarCodeScanner component from expo-barcode-scanner inside the Camera component. This should allow you to scan barcodes using the camera.

Expo BarCodeScanner : https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/

How to migrate from expo-barcode-scanner to expo-camera : https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/barcode-scanner-to-expo-camera.md
import React, { useState } from 'eact';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'eact-native';
import { Camera, useCameraPermissions } from 'expo-camera';
import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo-barcode-scanner';
import Screen from './Screen';
import TextHyperlink from '../components/TextHyperlink';

function ScannerScreen() {
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
  const [permission, requestPermission] = useCameraPermissions();

  if (!permission) {
      return <View />;
  }

  if (!permission.granted) {
      return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                  We need your permission to show the camera
              </Text>
              <Button onPress={requestPermission} title='grant permission' />
          </View>
      );
  }

  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ data }) => {
      console.log('lalalalala');
      if (data) {
          setScanned(true);
          setResult(data);
      }
  };

  const handleResult = () => {
      if (!result) return null;

      if (result.startsWith('http')) {
          return (
              <TextHyperlink
                  style={styles.resultlink}
                  text={result}
                  url={result}
              />
          );
      } else {
          return <Text style={styles.resulttext}>{result}</Text>;
      }
  };

  return (
      <Screen>
          <View style={styles.camerabox}>
              <Camera
                  style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
                  type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
              >
                  <BarCodeScanner
                      onBarCodeScanned={handleBarCodeScanned}
                      style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
                  />
              </Camera>
              {scanned && (
                  <Button
                      title={'Tap to Scan Again'}
                      onPress={() => setScanned(false)}
                  />
              )}
          </View>
          <View style={styles.textbox}>{handleResult()}</View>
      </Screen>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  camerabox: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      width: '100%',
  },
  resultlink: {
      color: 'blue',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      fontFamily: 'onospace',
      padding: 20,
      textDecorationLine: 'underline',
  },
  resulttext: {
      color: 'white',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      fontFamily: 'onospace',
      padding: 20,
  },
  textbox: {
      borderTopColor: 'blue',
      borderTopWidth: 3,
      alignItems: 'center',
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      width: '100%',
    },
});

export default ScannerScreen;




Expo 51 supports CameraView instead of Camera, so the problem persists: when I point to QR code, nothing happens. I also tried Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync() instead of useCameraPermissions(), but still nothing.

import { Camera, CameraType } from 'expo-camera/legacy';

